# How to authenticate PHP Laravel with Firebase Authentication

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, laravel-5.3

I am developing Web Application in PHP Laravel framework, and I am thinking to use Firebase as the backend Database and Authentication.

I would like to know how I could replace PHP Laravel default Auth with Firebase Auth?

What I understand from the Google Firebase WebSite, the Firebase Auth is built in JavaScript.

Some example source code it would be great.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @SimonSchnell - Not yet Sir.

Comment: now? would be interesting?

Comment: @SimonSchnell - Yes. I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

use this function

$auth= $firebase->getAuth();

$auth->verifyPassword($email,$password);